# How to add multiple query values to url

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to add multiple query string values at the current url but i'm not understanding how to do it.

I'm using `express` and `Nodejs`.

I've created a route that can read the values

```
router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {

    Post.find({}).populate('files').exec((err, posts) => {
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(req.query)

            res.render('home');
        }
    });
});
```

and in the home page i've set some links that add query values

```
<a href="?Value1=1">Value1</a>
<a href="?Value2=2">Value2</a>
<a href="?Value3=3">Value3</a>
```

but each time that i click one of them the url resets the query string and add the query value of the cicked link.

So how can i concatenate them?

Answer (score 1):

I have some confused with your question.

If you want your link will be `/?Value1=1&value2=2&value3=3`, you can use :

```
//script.js

let oldUrl = window.localtion;
let newUrl = oldUrl + '&value2` //and the same with value3
$('yourElement').attr('href')= newUrl; //yourElement maybe id,name,...etc
```

I hope it can help you !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to store all query string inside a variable to use them later and secondly, you need to parse current query, concatenate it with the previously stored ones and regenerate final query.

Here is an example:

```js
const qs = require('querystring')
let queries = {}
router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {

    Post.find({}).populate('files').exec((err, posts) => {
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            queries = Object.assign({}, queries, req.query)
            // this line will log concatenated query
            console.log(qs.stringify(queries))
            res.render('home');
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** Don't forget to install querystring module.

```
npm i querystring
```